# Null value condition is not working in my Big Query SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have worked on SQL for a long time. Now, I have just started learning Big Query.

Please see query below.

```
select 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM lead_qb_created_date)*100+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM lead_qb_created_date) as Lead_Create_YYYYMM,
COUNT(DISTINCT salesforce_lead_key) AS COUNT_LEADS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN FICO_9 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_LEADS_FICO_NOT_NULL

from `standardized_data.consumer_360`
where lead_qb_created_date >= '2018-01-01'

GROUP BY Lead_Create_YYYYMM
ORDER BY Lead_Create_YYYYMM
```

Here is the partial results:

```
Lead_Create_YYYYMM  COUNT_LEADS  COUNT_LEADS_FICO_NOT_NULL
0               201801        8992                      8992
1               201802        4343                      4343
2               201803        9227                      9227
```

I know that some rows have null fico. Then, why is my COUNT_LEADS and COUNT_LEADS_FICO_NOT_NULL showing the same values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the idea was to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` for `COUNT_LEADS_FICO_NOT_NULL` column?

Comment: Sergey, you are right..SUM gave me the answer I was looking for..I am going to delete this question as it is not really useful for anyone else..